# Angular drag and drop list nested

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm following this link 
    http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/advanced 
    for build a nested drag and drop. I have parent and child items, for parent items it working fine, i have added a list in  dnd-list="ItemsParent"  and dropped items for parent are added in this list. 
    I have second list for child items dnd-list="ItemsChild" when i dropped child items, items are getting added in parent list. Pleas suggest me how i can solve this issue.

```
Below is small part of my code:  
<div `dnd-list`=`ItemsParent`>
  <div data-ng-repeat="item in ItemsParent">
    <div dnd-list="ItemsChild">
      <div data-ng-repeat="chItems in ItemsChild">
          {{chItems.Name }}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, Probably you are not maintaining parent and child relationship. Your code should look like this

Below is small part of my code:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in ItemsParent">
      <div data-ng-repeat="chItems in item.ItemsChild">
          {{chItems.Name }}
      </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks, But for this issue i have disabled the parent if i want to move items of child.